# MySQL - Truncated incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I need to migrate some data from between to tables. The first has a varchar(255) field where a date is stored. I want to insert that date in a timestamp field in the second table.

The varchar field store the value in this ISO 8601 format: 2020-09-24T15:08:07+02:00.

I tried different conversions using STR_TO_DATE and casts but I always get the same error:

Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2020-06-01T09:38:08+02:00'

On selecting the value seems to be converted correctly:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(varcharDate,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s') = 2020-06-01 09:38:08
```

Comment: And your question is what exactly`?

Answer (score 1):

In would recommend

```
  SELECT CONVERT( '2020-06-01T09:38:08+02:00' , DATETIME)
```

STR_TO_DATE does the trick, but is usually slow.

You can run such a Query to test the performance using the column name instead of the text

```
 CREATE TABLE t2 (tz TIMESTAMP) SELECT CONVERT( '2020-06-01T09:38:08+02:00' , DATETIME)
```

Comment: I'm always getting the same: 
Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2020-06-01T09:38:08+02:00'
also tried to change the data type of the field to DATETIME but nothing has changed

Comment: please create a dbfiddle with some rows that produces the error.

Comment: @Carlo - What version of MySQL/MariaDB?  I suspect (without proof) that handling the 'T' and '+02:00' is a recent addition.

Comment: @RickJames i'm using version 10.4.14-MariaDB

Comment: this version can handle the convertion, like i said add some sample dat to show us the error

Answer (score 0):

You should create table with the `timestamp` datatype & then try to insert :

```
create table Timestamp_checking
(col_date timestamp(6) ) ;

0 row(s) affected

insert into Timestamp_checking values ('2020-06-01T09:38:08+02:00') 

1 row(s) affected   0.022 sec
```

Comment: Still getting the same error on my side, so probably is caused by mine MySQL version